# Implementing point search in a polygon using Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

There were some difficulties while implementing my app in Django. What the app should do:

- Accepts and saves Delivery zones as a set of coordinates;
- Accepts Couriers data with reference to the Delivery zone;
- Accepts the coordinates of Delivery location and returns Courier data and Delivery zone ID.

I solved two points, but there problems with the last one. I need to know if Delivery location is in Delivery zone or not. I found how to solve this problem in Python shell:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

p = GEOSGeometry(location, srid=4326)
DeliveryZone.objects.filter(coordinates__contains=p)
```

But I don't know how to implement this inside my app.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class DeliveryZone(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"#{self.id}"


class Courier(models.Model):
    delivery_zone = models.ForeignKey(DeliveryZone, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"#{self.id} {self.last_name}"


class Delivery(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"#{self.id}"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import DeliveryZoneSerializer, CourierSerializer, DeliverySerializer
from .models import DeliveryZone, Courier, Delivery


class DeliveryZoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DeliveryZone.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeliveryZoneSerializer


class CourierViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Courier.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourierSerializer


class DeliveryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeliverySerializer
```

I can provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use [a manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) for that. Then in django rest framework you would hook into `get_queryset` and remove `queryset`.

Pseudo code.

```py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class DeliveryViewSet(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeliverySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # put a ref to zone_id in your url
        zone_id = self.kwargs.get('zone_id')
        zone_instance = get_object_or_404(DeliveryZone, id=zone_id)
        # implement filter_by_zone in your manager
        return Delivery.objects.filter_by_zone(zone_instance).all()
```